# Balloon inflator rocker or micro switch stops working

Tags: motor, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, brushed-dc-motor, vacuum

I designed a balloon inflator that uses a 120v, 6.6A, 800w motor with a power load of 700 and unload of 772 and it uses two types of switches one is a micro switch (10A, 125v)used on the nozzles for when you press down the nozzles it inflates. The other is a rocker switch (10A 125v). The issue I keep having with some inflators is that after a few times of use the machine blows air continuously and the only way to turn of the inflator is to unplug it. Does anyone have any suggestions on why this keeps happening and how to fix the issue?[image][image][image]

Comment: What is "a power load of 700 and an unload of 772"?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you're seeing contact welding from running an inductive load.  The microswitch has a motor rating of 1/4 HP and your motor sounds like at least 1/2 HP if not more (746 W output power = 1 HP). Use the switch setup you have to drive a relay with a 120 VAC coil that is rated for at least 1 HP at 120 VAC. You should be able to find one from a reputable source (NOT Amazon, eBay, Alibaba, etc) for about $10. Your existing switches have probably been damaged somewhat so it might be a good time to replace those too.

Comment: This type of relay is commonly called a "contactor".   $10 seems ambitious, maybe I don't know the right shop.